# Adding newlines while writing text to a file

Tags: catcodes, write

Within a custom command, I'm doing the following to write to a file:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \newwrite\file
  \immediate\openout\file=foobar.tex
  \immediate\write\file{
    foo
    bar
    #1
    blarg
  }
  \immediate\closeout\file
}
```

Of course when I invoke it as `\mycommand{baz}`, I get the following contents in `foobar.tex`:

```
foo bar baz blarg
```

with all new lines turned into spaces by `LaTeX`. My question is, is there a way to output these lines into the file "as expected", i.e. with real new lines at the end of each line instead of a space? I'm thinking some `\catcode` wizardry should do the trick, but I'm not sure which character I need to redefine and to what category code.

**Update**

The solution in [cmhughes' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152475/19516) works perfectly. The only problem is when `#1` contains embedded newlines. I can of course send it to `mycommand` with its own slew of `^^J`, I was wondering if there is a way to avoid this.

Comment: you could use `^^J`

Comment: @cmhughes that looks like an answer to me:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're missing a `\newcommand` before `\mycommand` and a `[1]` after it.

First of all, it should be, at least,

```
\newwrite\file
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{
  \immediate\openout\file=foobar.tex
  \immediate\write\file{
    foo
    bar
    #1
    blarg
  }
  \immediate\closeout\file
}
```

or every call to `\mycommand` would allocate a new output stream. Now, let's see how to cope with the newlines. As others have observed, `^^J` is set as the `\newlinechar` in LaTeX, so we can use it. But, if you want that a write respects new lines also in calls such as

```
\mycommand{a
  b
  c}
```

you have to work harder. Here's a possibility, by changing the category code of `^^M`:

```
%\newlinechar`^^J % LaTeX already does this
\newwrite\file
\def\mycommand{\begingroup\obeylines\mycommandaux}
\begingroup\obeylines
\gdef\mycommandaux#1{%
  \obeylines%
  \def^^M{^^J}%
  \immediate\openout\file=foobar.tex%
  \immediate\write\file{%
    foo
    bar
    #1
    blarg% <- no new line at the end
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\file%
  \endgroup%
}
\endgroup


\mycommand{a
b
c}
```

Here's the contents of `foobar.tex`

```
foo
bar
a
b
c
blarg
```

There is an obvious limitation: `\mycommand` cannot be an argument to another command.

Comment: "I assume..." D'oh! Sorry, I posted the question at 3 AM after a long day. Thanks for the answer: it's exactly what I was looking for. Every day I see more value to learning the TeX internals...

Answer (score 16):

You can use `^^J` as follows

```
\mycommand{%
  \newwrite\file
  \immediate\openout\file=foobar.tex
  \immediate\write\file{%
    foo^^J%
    bar^^J%
    #1^^J%
    blarg^^J%
  }%
  \immediate\closeout\file%
}%
```

Comment: +1 This works and I have tried it already. Sorry I failed to mention this. The problem is when `#1` itself has newlines. I'll update my question to reflect this info.

Comment: Sorry, I had to accept egreg's answer as it does exactly what I want. My bad for failing to be more specific earlier.

Comment: Is it also possible to write space using that way somehow?