# Writing linebreak and tab to output file

Tags: beamer, pdftex, output

In LaTex Beamer (MikTex on Win7), I use my own following macro to write to a text file:

```
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{comment}
\openoutputfile{\myFile.txt}{comment}
\addtostream{comment}{FirstLine}
\newcommand{\MyNote}[1]
{
    \addtostream{comment}{#1}
}
```

In my frames, I use \MyNote{my new entry} to add lines

and lateron

```
\closeoutputstream{comment}
```

This is convenient, because I can continue the file and close it at the very end of my beamer document.

But I want a tab and a line break to appear in the output file.

The following attempts do **not** work (they don't cause a linebreak, but the commands appear in the output file):

```
\MyNote{My line \linebreak My other line}
\MyNote{My line \n My other line}
```

How can it be achieved? Just literally typing a linebreak (enter) whn I sue \MyNote would of course be even nicer.

**Edit:**

This works

```
\MyNote{My line ^^J My other line}
```

But how can I make this work:

```
\MyNote{My line 
My other line}
```

**A big leap**:

Basically, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152510/24115) helped me a lot.

The solution is here:

```
\usepackage{newfile}
\newoutputstream{comment}
\openoutputfile{\jobname.txt}{comment}
\def\MyNote{\begingroup\obeylines\mycommandaux}
\begingroup\obeylines
\gdef\mycommandaux#1{%
  \obeylines%
  \def^^M{^^J}%
    \addtostream{comment}{#1}
  \endgroup%
}
\endgroup
```

Line breaks work (as long as \MyNote is called outside a frame), but tabs still don't.

Comment: Did you try `^^J` ?

Comment: Awesome, that works. Is there a way to write an enter-stroke in \MyNote to the output file as ^^J?

Comment: @bogus See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152472/adding-newlines-while-writing-text-to-a-file

Comment: Tabs are `^^I`, may be `\catcode`\^^I=12` works?