# Defining a macro that writes content to an external file

Tags: external-files

I'd like to write a macro that has two arguments, `filename` and `content`. The macro - let's call it `\mywrite` - would write `content` to `filename`. The usage would look something like:

```
\mywrite{testfile.tex}{Hello, world!}
```

It would also be able to handle TeX commands, like:

```
\mywrite{testfile.tex}{%
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\end{itemize}
}
```

The contents of `testfile.tex` would be the complete itemized environment.

I've tried using variations of `fancyvrb`, `filecontents` and directly using `\write` commands to no avail.

Is this possible?

My goal (for what it's worth) is to be able to write content to an external file that I call again from inside the current file.

Comment: Related: [Adding newlines while writing text to a file](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/152472/5764)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you can use `\write` you need to open a file using `\newwrite` and `\openout`. One way to do what you want in a macro is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newwrite\mywriter% create a file handle
\newcommand\mywrite[2]{%
  \immediate\openout\mywriter=#1% set the file name and open for writing
  \immediate\write\mywriter{\unexpanded{#2}}% write without expanding
  \immediate\closeout\mywriter% close file
}

\begin{document}

\mywrite{testfile.tex}{
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

This may not be what you want, however, because it ignores line breaks. A better approach would be to use the `VerbatimOut` environment from the [fancyvrb](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{VerbatimOut}{testfile.tex}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item

  \item Second
  \end{itemize}
\end{VerbatimOut}

\end{document}
```

Neither of these approaches allows you to append to files, but if you are going to be writing lots of material to a given file then a macro/environment like this is probably not what you really want.

Comment: the `\unexpanded` command is what I was missing from the `\write` approach (I knew about `\immediate\openout`, etc.). Seems to work well. Thanks. Your `\VerbatimOut` approach isn't what I was looking for - it lacks the macro aspect. Whenever I put it into a macro everything breaks down - even a macro that has no arguments.